# How to call java method using EL?

Tags: jsp, el

I am using own java class and I have import in jsp page:

```
<%@page import="org.common.Common"%>
```

In my class `Common` i have method `public static String sayHello(String name);`

Then I have loop using JSTL

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.requestDataList}" var="requestLoop">
```

And I want call my method `sayHello` how?

I am getting syntax error when I call:

```
Common.sayHello(${requestLoop.Name})
```

Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: Really? Where is something about `forEach`?

Comment: what is there in `forEach`, its a loop you wanted to use the value returned by `requestLoop.Name` in your method so, what is the diffrence in the link provided?

Comment: Read my post again.

Answer (score 2):

If you need use **static method in JSP EL (${})**, You can do the next steps

You have the Java Code

```
public class WebUtils {
    public static String getSaludo(String name) {
        return "Hola " + name;
    }
}
```

Create a new file in WEB-INF/zetta.tld

```
    <taglib version="2.1">
        <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
        <short-name>zetta</short-name>
        <function>
            <name>getSaludo</name>
            <function-class>mx.zettaware.WebUtils</function-class>
            <function-signature>java.lang.String getSaludo(java.lang.String)
            </function-signature>
        </function>
    </taglib>
```

Now You can use the Java class with EL in  JSP

```
    <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/zetta.tld" prefix="zetta"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Zettaware Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Using ${zetta:getSaludo("Zamora")}</h3>
    </body>
    </html>
```